# Check if a transaction_id holds changes uncommitted

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

We have a problem of random sessions that leave their transactions open with changes uncommited and eventually blocking other users. Is it possible to query the server metadata to check if a certain transaction_id holds changes uncommitted ? (our ERP is written so it permanently has a transaction open, but it always should commit any change done as soon as possible).

I want to write a module on the ERP to log changes uncommited when none should exist (closing windows, etc. ...), to detect those bugs as soon as possible.

Comment: Use [sp_whoIsActive](http://whoisactive.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this as a starting point:

```sql
select st.session_id,
    dt.database_id,
    dt.database_transaction_log_bytes_used,
    dt.database_transaction_log_bytes_reserved, 
    datediff(second, s.last_request_end_time, getdate())
from sys.dm_tran_session_transactions as st
join sys.dm_tran_database_transactions as dt
    on dt.transaction_id = st.transaction_id
join sys.dm_exec_sessions as s
    on s.session_id = st.session_id;
```

You'll probably want to put some sort of threshold around amount of log used/reserved and/or how long the session has been idle.

Comment: So far `database_transaction_log_bytes_used > 0` seems to be exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this answer the question, but I think this will show if a transaction has done any writes\changes:

```
select top 1 1 from sys.dm_tran_database_transactions
where transaction_id = CURRENT_TRANSACTION_ID() 
and database_transaction_state = 4
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-tran-database-transactions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

4: The transaction has generated log records.

It even seems to work on `truncate table`, that supposedly is not being logged.